# Javascript image on hover with <li>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fadein

my menu consists of different names, and I'm trying to fade in/out a different image every time user hovers over one of the `<li>` elements. Each `<li>` element is connected to different id, so that a correct image fades in for the specific person.
The problem is that the fade in and fade out works on all of the `<ul>` elements under the specific `<li>` element. Would you know how I can fix this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#pau").mouseover(function() {
    $("#paup").fadeIn(600);
  });
  $("#pau").mouseout(function() {
    $("#paup").fadeOut(600);
  });
  $("#red").mouseover(function() {
    $("#redp").fadeIn(600);
  });
  $("#red").mouseout(function() {
    $("#redp").fadeOut(600);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='people'>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div id="red">Redpoppy Stories</div>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="http://www.redpoppystories.com" target="_blank">Blog</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/redpoppystories" target="_blank">Facebook</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://instagram.com/redpoppyzuz/" target="_blank">Instagram</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Vimeo</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li id="pau">
        <div>Paulinemma</div>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="http://www.diamondandunicorn.com" target="_blank">Blog</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/paulinemma" target="_blank">Facebook</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://instagram.com/paulinemma/" target="_blank">Instagram</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Vimeo</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Thank you very much for your comments.

Comment: where is id paup and redp

Comment: could you paste your code in jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `mouseover` to `mouseenter` and `mouseout` to `mouseleave` so moving the mouse over the children does not cause the events to be re-triggered.

Comment: Thank you very much! I've been trying to solve this for a long time

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want it to fade in when you mouse over the div with text "Redpoppy Stories" but not when you mouse over the list items below with the text 'Blog', 'Facebook' and 'Instagram'.

First in your second menu group you have the id='pau' on the list item instead of the div holding the text. Also I would use the jquery hover() method rather than mouseover and mouseout. The hover method takes to parameters. The first is the function to run when hover starts. The second is the function to run when hover ends.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#pau").hover(function(){ 
        $("#paup").fadeIn(600); 
    } , function(){
        $("#paup").fadeOut(600);
    });

    $("#red").hover(function(){
        $("#redp").fadeIn(600);
    }, function(){
        $("#redp").fadeOut(600);
    });
});
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0o724b6b/

Comment: Sorry for the incomplete description. @epascarello actually solved the issue perfectly